# Getting MissingResourceException when debugging in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, classpath

I imported a 3rd-party Java project into Eclipse that has the following block:

```
configSrc = (PropertyResourceBundle) ResourceBundle.getBundle(fName);
```

When I debug this project under Eclipse, I get an `MissingResourceException` exception at this point.

When I run the JAR of the project from command-line (RedHat 6, if that makes any difference), it runs fine without any exceptions. It's executed as follows:

```
java -classpath /export/home/user/proj:/export/home/user/proj/lib/dist.jar my.foo.bar.topClass arg1 arg2
```

where `/export/home/user/proj` is the root dir of that project and `dist.jar` is the JAR file.

I suspect that the reason for the exception is that I have to set `CLASSPATH` properly in Eclipse. How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your class to run, select debug as, select debug configurations, the panel opens with all options to debug, set class path or arguments whatever is needed.

Comment: I tried adding `-classpath ...` under `VM arguments` but that did not help. Also, there is a `Classapth` tab that has a `User entries` part that I thought is supposed to take care of the classpath settings for the project. If I need to make mods under that tab, how?